# Ember cli pagination - unable to receive model?

Tags: ember.js

Working with Ember 3.19 and trying to use ember-cli-pagination. I have all my posts from JSONplaceholder in the data-store under model type 'post'. I was able to view all the posts from the data-store without pagination but have been unsuccessful in implementing ember-cli-pagination. Console shows currentPage and totalPages as undefined. The Articles element shows in the ember inspector but blank in chrome. The PageNumbers element appears but it is rendered as <<< ... NaN >>>

Controller - articles.js

```
import Controller from "@ember/controller";
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";
import { alias, oneWay } from "@ember/object/computed";
import pagedArray from "ember-cli-pagination/computed/paged-array";
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service'

export default class ArticlesController extends Controller {
  // setup our query params
  queryParams: ["page", "perPage"];

  // set default values, can cause problems if left out
  // if value matches default, it won't display in the URL
  @tracked page = 1;
  @tracked perPage = 10;

  // can be called anything, I've called it pagedContent
  // remember to iterate over pagedContent in your template
  @pagedArray('model', {
    page: alias("parent.page"),
    perPage: alias("parent.perPage"),
  })
  pagedContent;

  // binding the property on the paged array
  // to a property on the controller
  @oneWay("pagedContent.totalPages") totalPages;
}
```

Handlebar - articles.hbs

```
<h2>Posts</h2>
<div>
<ul>
    {{#each @pagedContent as |post|}}
    <li>User: {{post.user}} Title: {{post.title}} - {{post.body}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</div>

<PageNumbers @content={{@pagedContent}} />
```

Model - post.js

```
import Model, { attr } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class ArticleModel extends Model {
  @attr title;
  @attr body;
  @attr userId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the `articles.hbs` file:

Since the `pagedContent` is defined in the corresponding controller and **not any kind of argument**, the property has to be used with `this` and not with `@`. Hence change this template code should work.

```html
<h2>Posts</h2>
<div>
<ul>
    {{#each this.pagedContent as |post|}}
    <li>User: {{post.user}} Title: {{post.title}} - {{post.body}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</div>

<PageNumbers @content={{this.pagedContent}} />
```

Also, there is a typo in the controller file. Since this is a class component, the qps has to defined like:

```js
queryParams = ["page", "perPage"];
```

Comment: I made those changes and I still get errors in the console for 'no int for currentPage val is undefined' and same output as before.

Comment: I moved everything from the controller into the component articles.js and now the PageNumbers renders and the controls work. Output is still blank however. Could this be that I'm not seeing my model insider the component js?

Comment: I can get this done using the controller itself. Check this twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/30bd47e70fdce3ca98feef25753a85c3?openFiles=controllers.application%5C.js%2C . Can you reproduce your issue here?